# Add loader for React-Flexbox-Grid into Webpack2 config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-flexbox-grid

I have tried endlessly to integrate a loader for React-Flexbox-Grid into my web pack config (shown below), but I receive error:

```
errors — client:119./~/flexboxgrid/dist/flexboxgrid.css
Module parse failed: /Users/---project-path---/node_modules/flexboxgrid/dist/flexboxgrid.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

This is the first time I have had to add in something like this, so I am not sure if I have been adding the 'include: /flexboxgrid/' in the correct place (I added it under the development/production rules), but it just returns the same error! Clearly what I am doing is wrong.

ps. I am using react-redux-webpack2-boilerplate

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProduction = nodeEnv === 'production';

const jsSourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './source');
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, './build');
const imgPath = path.join(__dirname, './source/assets/img');
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './source');
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  var env = JSON.stringify(require("./production-env.js"));
} else {
  var env = JSON.stringify(require("./development-env.js"));
}

// Common plugins
const plugins = [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    minChunks: Infinity,
    filename: 'vendor-[hash].js',
  }),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv),
      APPDATA: env,
    },
  }),
  new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(sourcePath, 'index.html'),
    path: buildPath,
    filename: 'index.html',
  }),
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
      postcss: [
        autoprefixer({
          browsers: [
            'last 3 version',
            'ie >= 10',
          ],
        }),
      ],
      context: sourcePath,
    },
  }),
];

// Common rules
const rules = [{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'babel-loader',
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|svg)$/,
    include: imgPath,
    use: 'url-loader?limit=20480&name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]',
  },
];

if (isProduction) {
  // Production plugins
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false,
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style-[hash].css')
  );

  // Production rules
  rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
    }),

  });
} else {
  // Development plugins
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new DashboardPlugin()
  );

  // Development rules
  rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      // Using source maps breaks urls in the CSS loader
      // https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/232
      // This comment solves it, but breaks testing from a local network
      // https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/232#issuecomment-240449998
      // 'css-loader?sourceMap',
      'css-loader',
      'postcss-loader',
      'sass-loader?sourceMap',
    ],

  });
}

module.exports = {
  devtool: isProduction ? 'eval' : 'source-map',
  context: jsSourcePath,
  entry: {
    js: './index.js',
    vendor: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      'es6-promise',
      'immutable',
      'isomorphic-fetch',
      'react-dom',
      'react-redux',
      'react-router',
      'react',
      'redux-thunk',
      'redux',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: buildPath,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'app-[hash].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.webpack-loader.js', '.web-loader.js', '.loader.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      jsSourcePath,
    ],
  },
  plugins,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: isProduction ? './build' : './source',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
    compress: isProduction,
    inline: !isProduction,
    hot: !isProduction,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    stats: {
      assets: true,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      hash: false,
      modules: false,
      publicPath: false,
      timings: true,
      version: false,
      warnings: true,
      colors: {
        green: '\u001b[32m',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: thats a css file, so add a css handler, you only have scss

Answer (score 0):

Its better to transform class properties.This kind of loader will help to solve this

```
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
```